# How to show edit delete button in one column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

Actually i am facing a little bit problem. I want to show Edit and Delete Button in one column But I am unable to do that. Let me share my code with you.

```
var dataTable;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        dataTable = $("#tableId").DataTable({

            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Home/GetAllStock",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Stock_Name", "autowidth": true },
                { "data": "Stock_UOM", "autowidth": true },
                {
                    "data": "Stock_ID", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                        return '<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="geteditstock(' + data + ')">Edit</button> <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="Delete(' + data + ')">Delete</button>'
                    }

                },
                {
                    "data": "Stock_ID", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                        return '<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="Delete(' + data + ')">Delete</button>'
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    });
```

I want Edit and Delete button show in one column adjacent to each other.
and my output is look like this.
[image: Screenshot1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change width from 50px to atleast 200px, remove the last column which is of no use and wrap the two buttons in a div. Hope this helps!.. Happy Coding!!

````
var dataTable;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        dataTable = $("#tableId").DataTable({

            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Home/GetAllStock",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Stock_Name", "autowidth": true },
                { "data": "Stock_UOM", "autowidth": true },
                {
                    "data": "Stock_ID", "width": "250px", "render": function (data) {
                        return '<div><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="geteditstock(' + data + ')">Edit</button> <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="Delete(' + data + ')">Delete</button></div>'
                    }

                }
            ]
        });
    });```
````

Comment: Good to know.. Happy Coding!!